# How do I format an bluetooth address as a btaddr?

Tags: c++, bluetooth, winsock

I have a bluetooth address (7C9EBD4CBFB2) that I need to connect to using winsock. This is my code, which returns error as -1, and won't connect to my device. How do I format this address to use as a btaddr? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
SOCKADDR_BTH sockAddr;
SOCKET btSocket;
int error;

int main() {
    btSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    memset(&sockAddr, 0, sizeof(sockAddr));
    sockAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    sockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
    sockAddr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    sockAddr.btAddr = 0x7C9EBD4CBFB2;
    error = connect(btSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
    cout << error;
}
```

Comment: The error in this line: sockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;. It must be sockAddr.serviceClassId = SerialPortServiceClass_UUID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `WSAStartup()` before `socket()`. You would have realized this sooner if you had been doing better error checking. See [Handling Winsock Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/handling-winsock-errors).

`socket()` would have returned `INVALID_SOCKET` (-1), and then `WSAGetLastError()` would have returned `WSANOTINITIALISED` (10093).

> Successful `WSAStartup` not yet performed.
>
> Either the application has not called `WSAStartup` or `WSAStartup` failed. The application may be accessing a socket that the current active task does not own (that is, trying to share a socket between tasks), or `WSACleanup` has been called too many times.

And then `connect()` would have failed with `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1), and `WSAGetLastError()` would have returned `WSAENOTSOCK` (10038).

> Socket operation on nonsocket.
>
> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for `select`, a member of an `fd_set` was not valid.

Per the [Bluetooth Programming with Windows Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-programming-with-windows-sockets) documentation:

> As with all Windows Sockets application programming, the WSAStartup function must be called to initiate Windows Sockets functionality and enable Bluetooth.

ALWAYS check error codes on system calls!

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int str2ba(const char *straddr, BTH_ADDR *btaddr)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int aaddr[6];
    BTH_ADDR tmpaddr = 0;

    if (std::sscanf(straddr, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
                    &aaddr[0], &aaddr[1], &aaddr[2],
                    &aaddr[3], &aaddr[4], &aaddr[5]) != 6)
        return 1;
    *btaddr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        tmpaddr = (BTH_ADDR) (aaddr[i] & 0xff);
        *btaddr = ((*btaddr) << 8) + tmpaddr;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    memset(&wsa, 0, sizeof(wsa));

    int error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);
    if (error != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup() failed, error: " << error;
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET btSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    if (btSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "socket() failed, error: " << error;
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKADDR_BTH sockAddr;
    memset(&sockAddr, 0, sizeof(sockAddr));
    sockAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    sockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
    sockAddr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    str2ba("7C:9E:BD:4C:BF:B2", &sockAddr.btAddr);

    if (connect(btSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "connect() failed, error: " << error;
        closesocket(btSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    // use btSocket as needed...

    closesocket(btSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that there was a better way to check for socket errors, but I didn't know how.

Comment: @IsaacW see [Handling Winsock Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/handling-winsock-errors)

Comment: I knew how after looking at your answer.